# Index statistics available for not existing index?

Tags: t-sql, indexing, statistics, sql-server-2012

I am running the following query to get index external fragmentation:

```
SELECT SCH.[name] as 'Schema' 
      ,TBL.[name] as 'Table' 
      ,IX.[name] as 'Index'
      ,IXStats.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent]
      ,IXStats.[page_count]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats] (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS IXStats
INNER JOIN [sys].[tables] AS TBL 
    on TBL.[object_id] = IXStats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] SCH 
    on TBL.[schema_id] = SCH.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] AS IX 
    ON IX.[object_id] = IXStats.[object_id]
    AND IXStats.[index_id] = IX.[index_id]
WHERE IXStats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY IXStats.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] DESC
```

And for several tables (on which there is no index or primary key) the query returns fragmentation.

How is this possible? Is SQL Server creating some internal indexes?

Comment: @DerU Yes, you are right - there is a `default constraint`. I am not able to get its fragmentation using Management studio, but is in this case fragmentation even matters?

Comment: i just checked dm_db_index_physical_stats in books online: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188917.aspx . it says: "Returns size and fragmentation information for the *data* and indexes". Here is my interpretation: a heap (with no indexes and no pk) can be stored on a disc in one consecutive block or be dispersed in several fragments. It posseses a certain fragmentation. The default contraint has nothing to do with fragmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you run your query and grab the index_id column too like so:

```
SELECT SCH.[name] as 'Schema' 
      ,TBL.[name] as 'Table' 
      ,IX.[name] as 'Index'
      ,IX.index_id
      ,IXStats.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent]
      ,IXStats.[page_count]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats] (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS IXStats
INNER JOIN [sys].[tables] AS TBL 
    on TBL.[object_id] = IXStats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] SCH 
    on TBL.[schema_id] = SCH.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] AS IX 
    ON IX.[object_id] = IXStats.[object_id]
    AND IXStats.[index_id] = IX.[index_id]
WHERE IXStats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY IXStats.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] DESC
```

You should see that tables that have no index defined for them have an ID of 0, this means that the table is a heap (i.e. a table with no clustered index).  If you see the index ID of 1, this means that the table is a clustered index.

See here for more info about heaps:

[Heaps (Tables without Clustered Indexes)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, could you tell if external fragmentation for such tables can affect performance (like it can do for a clustered index table) and how this fragmentation can be fixed as there is no index for rebuild (only in case if it can hit the performance)?

Comment: So, yes, it can impact performance, but you're likely to be getting more performance issues just using heaps anyway (table scans every time you look up a single value etc), you can run ALTER TABLE tableName REBUILD which will rebuild the heap but from a performance perspective I'd suggest you're better off concentrating on creating the right clustered/nonclustered indexes rather than worrying about fragmentation

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me clearing this. Yes, I am going to check for right indexes, just was interested about is there a way to de-fragmented it as in some situations using heap instead clustered table is proven to be better.